# xcode 4.3.3 iphone - Object leaked allocated object not referenced later

Tags: ios, xcode

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    self.listFeedConnection = nil;   // release our connection

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;   

    // create the queue to run our ParseOperation
    self.queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    // create an ParseOperation (NSOperation subclass) to parse the RSS feed data so that the UI is not blocked
    // "ownership of mediaListData has been transferred to the parse operation and should no longer be
    // referenced in this thread.
    //
    ParseOperation *parser = [[ParseOperation alloc] initWithData:listData delegate:self];

    [queue addOperation:parser]; // this will start the "ParseOperation"

    [parser release];
    [queue release];
    // ownership of mediaListData has been transferred to the parse operation
    // and should no longer be referenced in this thread
    self.listData = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc 
{
    [records release];
    [listFeedConnection release];
    [listData release];
    [queue release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Apologies - I'm getting the error on NSOperationQueue. Apparently not released correctly.  Please advise.

Comment: What exactly is the error?  What do you mean by "apparently not released correctly"?

Comment: NSOperationQueue 1. Method returns an Objective-C object with a +1 retain count.

Then on Parser code 2. Object leaked: allocated object not referenced later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the error message comes from Xcode static analyzer, keep in mind that it is not perfect and it may have false positives. Actually, I don't see any problem with your code, but would suggest trying and replacing it with this:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    self.listFeedConnection = nil;   // release our connection

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;   

    // create the queue to run our ParseOperation
    self.queue = [[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] autorelease];

    // create an ParseOperation (NSOperation subclass) to parse the RSS feed data so that the UI is not blocked
    // "ownership of mediaListData has been transferred to the parse operation and should no longer be
    // referenced in this thread.
    //
    ParseOperation *parser = [[[ParseOperation alloc] initWithData:listData delegate:self] autorelease];

    [queue addOperation:parser]; // this will start the "ParseOperation"

    // ownership of mediaListData has been transferred to the parse operation
    // and should no longer be referenced in this thread
    self.listData = nil;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It is the static Xcode analyzer. Cheers to helping a graphic designer in a sea of code.